# Setting no_proxy for a server - Terraform (infoblox)

Tags: terraform, infoblox

Hello I am trying to provision resources on Infoblox using terraform. It looks like proxy is blocking the ip. How do I set no proxy in my terraform config?

```
provider "infoblox" {
  username = "The username here"
  password = "The password here"
  server = "10.0.0.1"
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    infoblox = {
      source  = "infobloxopen/infoblox"
      version = "2.4.1"
    }
  }
}
```

Error Message

```
╷
│ Error: Creation of network block failed in network view (default) : WAPI request error: 502('502 Connection timed out')
│ Contents:
│ <HEAD><TITLE>Connection timed out</TITLE></HEAD>
│ <BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black"><H1>Connection timed out</H1><HR>
│ <FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
│ Description: Connection timed out</B></FONT>
│ <HR>
│ <!-- default "Connection timed out" response (502) -->
│ </BODY>
```

When I do a curl, it works using the command below

```
export no_proxy=10.0.0.1

curl -kvv -u username:password -c cookies.txt -X GET "https://10.0.0.1/wapi/v2.12/record:host?_return_as_object=1"
```

Also, when I run the above configuration in an environment with no proxy issue. It works

Comment: Are you seeing any errors? If so, please add them to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set the NO_PROXY as well

```
export NO_PROXY=10.0.0.1
```